# How to call __init__ method of the parent class after dynamic class creation in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, super

I want dynamically create a class from two Base classes (ExampleTestRun and Thread). Main purpose for this is to start ExampleTestRun method "run" in a thread (by calling Thread class method "start"). I never used super() in Python. Maybe with it would be an answer?

```
from threading import Thread

class BaseTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class ExampleTestRun(BaseTest):

    def run(self):

        try:
            a = int('A')
        except Exception as ex:
            print ex



if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_class = type('TestClass', (ExampleTestRun, Thread), {})
    test = test_class()
    test.start()
```

I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/Workspaces/PyCharmWorkspace/ElgsisTests/src/mcltests/mcltransparent/run.py", line 30, in <module>
    test.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 737, in start
    raise RuntimeError("thread.__init__() not called")
RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called
```

Comment: Why did you define an empty `__init__` method?

Comment: BrenBarn: In BaseTest?

Comment: Yes.  If you just remove that it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws that error becuase you are overriding the `__init__` of the newly created class. Replacing that re-definition with `pass` altogether will fix it:

```
class BaseTest(object):
    pass
```

Of course if you want to expand on the original constructor, you will have to resort to `super`. So the full code will look like this:

```
from threading import Thread

class BaseTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BaseTest, self).__init__()

class ExampleTestRun(BaseTest):

    def run(self):

        try:
            a = int('A')
        except Exception as ex:
            print ex

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_class = type('TestClass', (ExampleTestRun, Thread), {})
    test = test_class()
    test.start()
```

Comment: As I said - I never used super before, so not familiar with it's behavior and didn't know difference between using super or simply calling ParentClass.__init__(self) method in ChildClass __init__ method. Thank you!